# Fischer's exact test clarification

Tags: statistics

Let's say I have two groups and I'm interested in determining whether 2 sets of categorical features are independent. Let's say my categorical features are not ordinal and thus I want to use the Fischer's test and cannot use the wilcoxon test alternative.
Let's say for one of my categorical features, we have some categories that are observed in group 2 but not in group 1.
For example:
group 1: [1,2,3,4,1,1,2,3,1]
group 2: [1,2,3,5,5,5,2,3,1]

categorical value 5 is only observed in group 2 but not in group 1. For my other categorical feature, the categorical values are the same between group 1 and group 2.
Is it still valid to use the Fischer's test to quantify independence between group 1 and group 2?